# How to add a link to a FancyBox gallery rather then using an image (WordPress - Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: wordpress, fancybox-2, custom-fields

I am trying to add a non image link to a FancyBox gallery.  I am also using the Advanced Custom Fields Repeater field.

I have this so far:

```
    <a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="http://website.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Burnham1.jpg">
    <p>Show Plans</p>
    </a>

    <?php if( get_field('lightbox_images') ): ?>

    <?php while( has_sub_field('lightbox_images') ): ?>

    <a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>"></a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm unsure of what the href value should be in the non image link in order to fire the gallery up?  At the moment I just have it hardcoded but this should be editable within WordPress and also using this method means this initially link adds an extra duplicate image to the gallery which I do not want.

All ideas are greatly welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: The link that fires the gallery doesn't have to have the same *class* or `rel` (`data-fancybox-group`) as the elements of the gallery. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17349002/1055987 for examples of manual `trigger` from another link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent showing same image when there are two anchors opening the same gallery with fancy box on same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338918/how-to-prevent-showing-same-image-when-there-are-two-anchors-opening-the-same-ga)